Is strict increasingness required to validate this implication
Given this problem :

Prove that the equation $x^3+2\sqrt x +x -5=0$ has only one positive real solution $\alpha$ and check that $1<\alpha<2$.

We use the continuity and strict monotonicity to justify existence and unicity of $\alpha$.
My question is related to the second part of the question :
We would like to prove that $1<\alpha<2$
The simplest way would be to compare the images $f(1)$ , $f(2)$ and $f(\alpha)$ the latter being 0 by definition of $\alpha$.
My question is :
Given an inequality $f(a) < f(b)$ do we need 'increasingness' (only) or 'strict increasingness' (of $f$ on an interval containing both of course) to draw from it that $a<b$ ?
I think increasingness is enough since the implication :
$$f(a)<f(b)\implies a<b$$
is true by contrapositive for 'increasing' functions (not strict ones)
thanks for any response.

I'm not sure why you're considering increasiningness, when the Intermediate Value Theorem works.

we're asked to prove there is "only" one solution (that requires injectivityà

It suffices that the function is increasing.
Definition:

A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is increasing if for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, if $x<y$ then $f(x)\leq f(y)$.
A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly increasing if for every $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, if $x<y$ then $f(x)<f(y)$.

Lemma: Let $f$ be an increasing function. If $f(a)<f(b)$ then $a<b$.
Proof: Assume by contradiction that $b\leq a$. If $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$ and we have a contradiction. Otherwise assume that $b<a$, then since $f$ is increasing we have that $f(b)\leq f(a)$. This is a contradiction since $f(a)<f(b)$.
